# HTML only- create a popup window from image

Tags: html, modal-dialog, popup, scrollbar, hide

I have a very simple HTML web page that has one large image on it with several text boxes (drawn in the image) that I would like to have a user click on and a popup window open up with more text. Currently, I'm using hotspots and the behaviors tag in Dreamweaver to call a pop-up window for each box on the image.

Q1 - How do I hide the scrollbars on the popup window in HTML?

Q2 - Is there a better way to do this with little coding like a modal popup? I have lots of these popups with different text in each I will need.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp

Answer (score 0):

To hide the scroll bar there is some CSS you can use, attached below. And for making popups, I have never tried hotspot and behavior tag however I just created one a few days ago using position absolute and using display none and block. Basically, you have to create the whole design of your popup anywhere in the code and you then set it to display: none, and whatever click you have for it to pop up, you add a little javascript function to it which will change the properties of that popup to display: block or anything else that you are using.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

Comment: This is my popup code now-where would I add that code above?

<map name="Map"><area shape="rect" coords="38,58,97,85" href="testwindow.shtml" target="new" onMouseOver="MM_openBrWindow('teswindow.shtml','','width=480,height=640')">

Comment: You can give an id/classname to the map tag and then simply use #idname::-webkit-scrollbar {...} in the CSS section. In case it doesn't work try using display none inside the webkit-scrollbar{...}.

Comment: I added this code

</script>
 
 #Map::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

</head>

my map is

<map name="Map"><area shape="rect" coords="38,58,97,85" href="testwindow.shtml" target="new" onMouseOver="MM_openBrWindow('teswindow.shtml','','width=480,height=640')">
  <area shape="rect" coords="38,169,96,206" href="#" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('docs_paym.shtml','','width=250,height=250')" overflow: hidden;>

Comment: It doesn't seem to work

Comment: No not this way, you have to put this part of the code inside the style tag and then in the javascript you will write a function like the following. function openPopUp(){document.getElementByID('idhere').style.display = 'block'} and in the CSS of this popup you will write: #idhere {display:none}. And for whichever button you want to click (it can be any tag) just put this there: onclick="openPopUp()". And put the script tag right before the </body> tag not in the head tag. Hope this works.

Comment: That is a non-standard property and won't work on Firefox or IE.

Comment: Lost here guys...

Comment: I would like to do all this without any javascripting, like using this

 overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: To just hide the scrollbars you can use overflow-y: hidden, if simple overflow is not working and the scroll is on the y-axis. Otherwise, just use #idname ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;}. This always works for me without using any Javascript.